# Can I remove create table permission in postgresql 8.3?

Tags: postgresql

Using postgresql 8.3, I've created a read only user like this:

`create role reportuser with login password 'secret';`

and then granted select to all the tables this user needs to access.

but I see this user can `create table x (...` and insert/update/delete/drop the table.

Is there a way to remove create table permissions for this user on this database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Revoke privileges from public schema.

Comment: Looks like `revoke create on schema public from public;` works.